# Getting file's tag in java in windows OS

Tags: java, file

We can add tags like 'Favourite', 'Rock' and 'Romantic' to mp4 files in windows machine. Is it possible to get tag name of a file in Java?

Comment: I think you would probably have to use an API for this.  If not, then you would need to parse the binary content yourself and extract out the tag.  The MP4 tag I believe is not a standard part of the NT file system.

Comment: Thanks. Which APIs / open source libraries i can use for this scenario?